# knowing if a site was published in release mode or debug mode

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

How can I tell the difference between a website that has been published in **release** mode and the same website that was published in **debug** mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell from ILDASM if an assembly is debug or release build.

http://blogs.msmvps.com/bill/2004/06/17/how-to-tell-if-an-existing-assembly-is-debug-or-release-build/

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you want to check programatically if the Website is running in debug mode. If this is really your question, then you may have a look at this [Blog post from Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/10228.aspx).

Don't forget to read the comments, as there are other solutions.

Rick's solution:

```
bool isInDebugMode = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

if it were published in debug mode with debug=true in the web.config then there would be a little bit of a performance hit. also if you can access the server then debug mode may mean the presence of .pdb files

apart from that i am not sure you can

Comment: in both cases when i publish both in release and debug i have pdb files from other projects in my solution... that are refrenced from the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# Preprocessor Directives: #IF DEBUG

```
#if DEBUG 
//Put code in here to show it's in debug mode.
//like.....
DebugMessageLabel.Visible = true;
#endif
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx